# Javascript: Getting a key value from an object function

Tags: javascript, function, object

Task is to get one of the key values from the object function to print to the console but having a spot of bother.

```
var chosenColor = function getThingsByColor(color){

  var things = {

    red: "This is a red thing",
    blue: "This is a blue thing",
    orange: "This is an orange thing"

  };

  return things[color] || "Sorry no color found";

}

coonsole.log(chosenColor('red'));
```

Result is red undefined.

Comment: is this your code you run at your computer? or a typo when you write it by yourself like `console.log(chosenColor(red));` and you forget the `'` around the `red`

Comment: btw: why you assign the function `getThingsByColor` to a variable `chosenColor ` and not call directly the function `getThingsByColor`? thats not a normal javascript coding style

Comment: There is a spelling mistake for `coonsole`. It should be `console`. Otherwise it works fine.

Comment: I'm doing the JS Fundamentals course from Tuts+ and they say its recommended the function be named as well as the variable. Dont shoot the messenger! ...but if you suggest a better way of writing, Im happy to take your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function works fine. I'm assuming you don't see the result printed out in the console. Make sure you have the 'All' tab selected for Console in your Dev Tools

Comment: Got it working now. Thanks guys. Really appreciate that. Must pay more attention to my spelling.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

algorithm is fine. coonsole => console ?